# Do value and key of additive attention need to have the same dimension?

Tags: neural-networks, keras, attention

For the documented tensorflow-keras implementation of additive attention, it is stated that the input tensors are:

- query: Query Tensor of shape `[batch_size, Tq, dim]`.
- value: Value    Tensor of shape `[batch_size, Tv, dim]`.
- key: Optional key Tensor of  shape `[batch_size, Tv, dim]`.

Now, it is clear that query and value need to have the same **dim** because they are going to be summed component-wise

```
scores = tf.reduce_sum(tf.tanh(query + key), axis=-1)
```

but I can not see why the key needs to have the same **dim** that either value or query. Is is just some implementation trick for this concrete library, or has it got a deeper justification?

Answer (score 1):

In this implementation, yes, but the `query` and `key` variables correspond to a linear projection of the decoder and encoder states into the same dimension.

The original Bahdanau's paper describes the computation in a formula in Appendix A.1.2

[image]

which has its equivalent in [the TF Keras code here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.8.0/keras/layers/dense_attention.py#L501). The `scale` variable corresponds to the weight vector $v_a$ and the dot product of $v_a$ with the output of the $\tanh$ function is implemented as element-wise multiplication first followed by `tf.reduce_sum`.

Further, the equation contains a projection of the decoder state $W_as_{i-1}$ and of the encoder states $U_ah_j$. These projections are into the same dimension so that they can be summed. However, the states $s_i$ and $h_j$ themselves do not have to be of the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a quirk of the implementation. There is a trainable scale (enabled by default) that depends on the dimension of the keys, but as in Keras `AdditiveAttention` the keys are an optional parameter, this dimension is extracted from the values.